# Notation for arguments by means of ifthen package

Tags: macros, conditionals, logic, ifthenelse

I have this idea to create a piece of code that would allow me for a handy introduction of arguments in my notes for students, by which I mean this kind of fractional notation:

[image]

I need a command that would adjust the horizontal line by measuring premises and conclusion, and would add 0.5em (or whatever) on each side beyond the sentences. Using `ifthen` package I came up with this very imperfect (to put it mildly) three-argument `\inference` command:

```
\newlength{\premiseone}
\newlength{\premisetwo}
\newlength{\conclusion}
\newcommand{\argument}[3]{%
\settowidth{\premiseone}{#1}
\settowidth{\premisetwo}{#2}
\settowidth{\conclusion}{#3}
\addtolength{\premiseone}{1em}
\addtolength{\premisetwo}{1em}
\addtolength{\conclusion}{1em}
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\premiseone > \premisetwo}}%
{\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\premiseone > \conclusion}}%
{\dfrac{\parbox{\premiseone}{\center #1\\#2}}{\mbox{#3}}}%
{\dfrac{\parbox{\conclusion}{\center #1\\#2}}{\mbox{#3}}}%
}
```

It is specifically designed for arguments with exactly two premises and has rather unwelcome features because of it. For example, if I write, e.g., `\argument{the only premise}{}{the consequence}`, LaTeX complains that there is no line to end, and If I add some empty box I have this unwanted additional space, either above the argument or inside it:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Here are my questions to you:

1. How could I get round the problem of additional spaces? That is, how could I skip some arguments by writing `\argument{the only premise}{}{the consequence}` without obtaining this additional vertical space (either above or inside)?
2. Is there any relatively easy way to build a command which would not be designed for a specific number of premises, but would work in a similar way as mine yet for any finite number of premises? Of course, I could always build `\argumentone`, `\arguemtttwo`, `\argumentthree`, but this is going round the houses.

Comment: What is wrong with a simple `tabular`?

Comment: Well, nothing I suppose :) This is mainly curiosity driven question, I am courious how this could be written in LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with a simple `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\inference}[3][t]{%
   \begingroup
   \def\and{\\}%
   \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{\enspace}c@{\enspace}}
   #2 \\
   \hline
   #3
   \end{tabular}%
   \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

First example:
\inference{John is taller than Jane}{John is taller than Judy}

\bigskip

Second example:
\inference{John is taller than Jane \and Jane is taller than Judy}{John is taller than Judy}

\bigskip

Third example (vertically centred):
\inference[c]{John is taller than Jane \and Jane is taller than Judy \and Whatever else}{John is taller than Judy}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I added an optional argument for vertical placing. Of course, further additional space above/below the tabular can be added (that will depend on how this thing is used in a real document).

Comment: Much simpler than my original idea, and does exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!